# How can I loop and compare the data present between two arrays in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two arrays which both have data, what I want to do is to loop through each array and compare the data between the arrays one array is coming from the Post Method and another array has data from the database, so the comparison has to be done to check if the data is present in database to be updated else it should be inserted as a new a record.

Below is my code snapshot

```
@Autowired
private OrderRepository orderRepository; 


public void process_data(String ordercode, List<Order> order) {
                
List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<>(); 
List<Order> orderData = orderRepository.findOrder(ordercode);

// here is where I want to compare the data between two array lists of order and orderData
   using a for loop

for(var data : order) {  // here is only one array present how can I add the second array list so that I can compare the data present between the two array lists

}
```

Comment: 1# Implement an equals method in the class Order. 2# For each element in your "localDataList", check if it is present in the "databaseDataList". 3# If it is not, create it. Have fun with your homework! :)

Comment: Btw: Arrays are not Lists.

Comment: Thanks @DavidWeber for your quick response how can I implement an equal method in the class order can you show me an example, sorry I'm a beginner

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts

Answer (score 1):

This issue isn't really related to Spring Boot. If your order object is identified uniquely by an ID, you can write a private method to check if a certain ID exists in an order list. Then, in the process_data method, iterate through the order list brought by the request, determining if each element exists in the DB list. If it does, update it; otherwise, insert it.

```
public void process_data(String ordercode, List<Order> order) {
    List<Order> orderData = orderRepository.findOrder(ordercode);
    for (Order r : order) {
        if (!existsInDb(r.getId(), orderData)) {
            //do insert
        } else {
            //do update
        }
    }
}
private boolean existsInDb(String id, List<Order> orderData) {
    for (Order order : orderData) {
        if (order.getId().equals(id)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with springboot. As far as I understand, you will get a list of order from post request and you need to check if any order is in DB. There should be a id with each order you get in orderlist from your post request. So, you don't need to get the order list from DB at once. Instead, you can do like this:

```
    public void process_data(String ordercode, List<Order> order) {
                
       List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<>(); 


       for(var data : order) { 
           if(!orderRepository.existsById(order.getId())) {
              //Oder is not present in DB
           }

       }
   }
```

Comment: So you recommend, doing a database requests for every entry in the list? 5000 entries = 5000 requests?

Comment: If you find by id, then it's a constant time lookUp and shouldn't be an issue, and if you get the whole list at once from DB, and DB has 1 million records, then should you load it at once? :)

Comment: Valid point, my comment was not precise enough. You could take the ids and execute a single request with them - not loadById(id), but loadByIds(collection). :)

Comment: Yes, that will do, but from DB's point of view, it will be same as calling by id each time. And, extra overhead will be checking each entry using n^2 loop.

Comment: I like this discussion! Loading and comparing entries in-memory is generally more efficient than loading and comparing them separately. In-memory operations are faster as they minimize the overhead of database queries and network communication.

Comment: But: I think we are both right. It depends on the situation. Where is the db located, how much data must be checked, data structure. I think the most efficient way is to just work with the primary keys using the lowest amount of db-requests.

Comment: If the given list is small, then your approach works better, but if the given list is lage, then I think, 'existsById' subquery for each element will perform better.

Comment: Thanks so much DavidWeber and @Md Wahidul Azam for your suggestions this is very fruitfuly discussion I have learned a lot, since the given list is large even if I try existsById method even though it works however the execution time becomes large for every request average time 20 minutes per request for it to complete so what else can I do to optimize the execution time

Comment: It's really tough to give a solution blindly. If you can exactly share the scenario and what you really need to do, then it might be helpful to come up with a solution.

Comment: @JanethJackson, probably I have understood your issue. You are trying to insert or update one by one. Instead of that, try using JDBC batching technique. Do some digging with JDBC batching and I'm sure you will understand what you should do.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MdWahidulAzam let me have a deep dive into JDBC batching technique hope I will get something and start from their, I really appreciate your support guys 

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

JPA repo:

```
public interface YourEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<YourEntity, Long> {
@Query("SELECT id FROM YourEntity")
List<Long?> findAllIds();
}
```

YourService:

```
@Service
public class YourEntityService {
    @Autowired
    private YourEntityRepository repository;

    public List<Long> findIdsNotInDatabase(List<Long> idList) {
        Set<Long> existingIds = new HashSet<>(repository.findAllIds());
        return idList.stream().filter(id -> !existingIds.contains(id)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

This will just get the ids of your datasets, which will be much faster than loading the entities completely.

After that, the filter extracts the "not available ids".